# replace values based on Number of duplicate rows are occured

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe ,that looks like this

```
       site  Active
0     deals  Active
1     deals  Active
2     deals  Active
3  discount  Active
4  discount  Active
```

i don't want to drop the duplicate items, but i want to change the Active columns value based on Site column,for example Active  has to change inactive based on  duplicate item in site column,last duplicate item has to Active, other than that Inactive

Expected

```
       site    Active
0     deals  InActive
1     deals  InActive
2     deals    Active
3  discount  InActive
4  discount    Active
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep='last'` and pass to [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for set new values:

```
df.loc[df['site'].duplicated(keep='last'), 'Active'] = 'InActive'
print (df)
       site    Active
0     deals  InActive
1     deals  InActive
2     deals    Active
3  discount  InActive
4  discount    Active
```

Comment: thank you  ,also i want to print the output in a new row ,i tried mapping functions  but it didn't  work

Comment: @shamlishankar - Not understand, can you explain more?

Comment: @shamlishankar - What doeas mean `print the output in a new row` ?

Comment: @shamlishankar - do you want `print (df['active'])` ?

Comment: Or `df['new'] = df['active']` ?

Comment: i want to print our output into a new column

Comment: @shamlishankar - I ama  bit confused, is possible add expected output from sample data by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65305660/edit) ? Or you need `for i in df['active']: print (i)` ?

Comment: i want to add a new column next to Active column with the same result  of our code

Comment: @shamlishankar - then use `df['new'] = df['active']`